# SpringMVC download file,the response result has data but explorer can't download file

Tags: spring-mvc, download, response

As the title says.
I set the values in java like this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + targetName);
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

I debugged in chrome explorer, and the response body is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: And how are you returning the result? nice that you set headers, but what else do you do.

Comment: You should post more code of controller method.

Comment: Yes. After the header was set, I use FileInputStream and FileOutputStream from response.getOutputStream() to write the content.
And at last, the flushing and closing streams operation is handled.
Then return void case the download action will be handled to explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved by changing the submit method in JS file.
At first I send request by this:
    Ext.Ajax.request({
    utl:'',
    params:{},
    method:'POST'
    });
Butajax can't download a file but can receive json/html/js/string format body.
So in extjs, if you want to download file, DO NOT USE ajax request.
And maybe you'll need use native javascript to do it.
For example:
    var form = document.createElement("form);
    form.method='POST';
    form.action='/';
    //deal with data

```
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```